# Break loop on new command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot that controls some RGB lights. I want a pattern to repeat. However, I need the loop to break as soon as any new command is typed.

```
@client.command()
async def rainbow(ctx):
    await ctx.send("It is rainbow")
    while True:
     rainbow_cycle(0.001)
```

I know while true loops can't be broken but I do not know another way to loop this function. If the full code is needed here is the Github link https://github.com/MichaelMediaGroup/Discord_controlled_lights/blob/main/discord/main.py

Thank you for the help

Comment: do u want to break the loop by entering an another command by the same user or even by some other person?

Comment: The while loop and `rainbow_cycle` are **blocking**. Your bot won't even be able to process other commands while this is going on, let alone interact with them. The way to go would probably be to define your rainbow cycle as a [task](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) and have your rainbow command start the task loop, while all other commands stop it if it is active (preferably via a [pre-invoke hook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.before_invoke))

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the best option I think but it should work:

You could create a new global value for the loop, like this:

```
loop = False;

@client.command()
async def rainbow(ctx):
    await ctx.send("It is rainbow")
    global loop
    loop = True
    while loop:
        rainbow_cycle(0.001)


@client.command()
async def anothercommand(ctx):
    global loop
    loop = False
    #Some other stuff here
```

Comment: While this moves the control of the loop onto the global scope, there still is the giant issue of a fully blocking `while True` loop in the command. That alone will prevent the bot from processing any other commands while the rainbow is running. If a blocking while loop is to be used, it absolutely needs to run in a separate thread

Comment: I agree, he won't be able to use other commands. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the best practice make a `while` loop here. Instead use `tasks.loop()` available in the discord module that you are using.
Do note this has to manually imported from `discord.ext`
So it'll look something like this :

```py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

@bot.command
async def rainbow(ctx):
    await ctx.send("It is rainbow")
    if rainbow_.is_running():
        rainbow_.stop()
    else:
        rainbow_.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=0)
async def rainbow_():
    # Do your things here
    rainbow_cycle(0.001)
```

Now we have created a non-blocking loop, this loop can be started / stopped by using your command.

**Do note** :

1] Do not use blocking commands like `sleep` inside your tasks (if you want sleep, use `asyncio.sleep(foo)` instead)

2] Do not not start `rainbow_` under `on_ready`, because `on_ready` gets called multiple times and can create unnecessary instances, however if you do want to start task when ready then make sure it isn't already running first.